# Wiedemann-Franz law derivation book recommendation

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, resource-recommendations

Can you recommend a good book with a thorough derivation. I know I'm more likely to find in a condensed matter book or a book on conductors but any recommendation would be appreciated, bonus if it includes the Casimir effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am citing the books in APA citation format:

- [1] Jones, William; March, Norman H. (1985). Theoretical Solid State
  Physics. Courier Dover Publications. ISBN 0-486-65016-2.
- [2]  Franz,    R.; Wiedemann, G. (1853). "Ueber die
  Wärme-Leitungsfähigkeit der    Metalle". Annalen der Physik (in
  German). 165 (8): 497–531.    Bibcode:1853AnP...165..497F.
  doi:10.1002/andp.18531650802
- [3]    Mizutani, Uichiro (2003). Introduction to the Electron Theory
  of    Metals. CAMBRIDGE UNIVERSITY PRESS. ISBN 9780511612626. Thermal
  conductivity: theory, properties, and applications, edited by Terry
  Tritt, Kluwer Academic / Plenum Publishers, New York (2004), ISBN
  978-0-387-26017-4
- [4] Thermal conductivity: theory, properties, and    applications,
  edited by Terry Tritt, Kluwer Academic / Plenum    Publishers, New
  York (2004), ISBN 978-0-387-26017-4
- [5]  Kittel, C.,

  2005. Introduction to Solid State Physics. John Wiley and Sons
- [6] Rosenberg, H. 2004. The Solid State. Oxford University Press
- [7] K.    Gloos, C. Mitschka, F. Pobell and P. Smeibidl. Cryogenics,
  30 (1990),    p. 14, doi:10.1016/0011-2275(90)90107-N
- [8] A. J. Minnich, M. S.    Dresselhaus, Z. F. Ren and G. Chen. Bulk
  nanostructured    thermoelectric materials: current research and
  future prospects,    Energy & Environmental Science, 2009, 2,
  466–479,    doi:10.1039/b822664b
- [9] Paothep Pichanusakorn, Prabhakar Bandaru.    Nanostructured
  thermoelectrics, Materials Science and Engineering: R:    Reports,
  Volume 67, Issues 2–4, 29 January 2010, pages 19–63, ISSN
  0927-796X, doi:10.1016/j.mser.2009.10.001
- [10] Wakeham, Nicholas;    Bangura, Alimamy F.; Xu, Xiaofeng;
  Mercure, Jean-Francois;    Greenblatt, Martha; Hussey, Nigel E.
  (2011-07-19). "Gross violation    of the Wiedemann–Franz law in a
  quasi-one-dimensional conductor".    Nature Communications. 2.
  Bibcode:2011NatCo...2E.396W.    doi:10.1038/ncomms1406. ISSN
  2041-1723. PMC 3144592. PMID 21772267
- [11]  "Bristol physicists break 150-year-old law". Retrieved
  2017-01-28.
- [12]  Lee, Sangwook; Hippalgaonkar, Kedar; Yang, Fan;    Hong,
  Jiawang; Ko, Changhyun; Suh, Joonki; Liu, Kai; Wang, Kevin;    Urban,
  Jeffrey J. (2017-01-27). "Anomalously low electronic thermal
  conductivity in metallic vanadium dioxide". Science. 355 (6323):
  371–374. Bibcode:2017Sci...355..371L. doi:10.1126/science.aag0410.
  ISSN 0036-8075. PMID 28126811
- [13] ang, Sarah (2017-01-26). "For This    Metal, Electricity Flows,
  But Not the Heat | Berkeley Lab". News    Center. Retrieved
  2017-01-28.
- [14] Jonson, M., & Mahan, G. D. (1980). Mott's formula for the thermopower and the Wiedemann-Franz law. Physical Review B, 21(10), 4223.
- [15] Graf, M. J., Yip, S. K., Sauls, J. A., & Rainer, D. (1996). Electronic thermal conductivity and the Wiedemann-Franz law for unconventional superconductors. Physical Review B, 53(22), 15147.
- [16] Mahan, G. D., & Bartkowiak, M. (1999). Wiedemann–Franz law at boundaries. Applied physics letters, 74(7), 953-954.
- [17] Kubala, B., König, J., & Pekola, J. (2008). Violation of the Wiedemann-Franz law in a single-electron transistor. Physical review letters, 100(6), 066801.
- [18] Crossno, J., Shi, J. K., Wang, K., Liu, X., Harzheim, A., Lucas, A., ... & Ohki, T. A. (2016). Observation of the Dirac fluid and the breakdown of the Wiedemann-Franz law in graphene. Science, 351(6277), 1058-1061.
- [19] Chester, G. V., & Thellung, A. (1961). The law of Wiedemann and Franz. Proceedings of the Physical Society, 77(5), 1005.
- [20] Tanatar, M. A., Paglione, J., Petrovic, C., & Taillefer, L. (2007). Anisotropic violation of the Wiedemann-Franz law at a quantum critical point. Science, 316(5829), 1320-1322.
- [21] Wakeham, N., Bangura, A. F., Xu, X., Mercure, J. F., Greenblatt, M., & Hussey, N. E. (2011). Gross violation of the Wiedemann–Franz law in a quasi-one-dimensional conductor. Nature communications, 2, 396.
- [22] Völklein, F., Reith, H., Cornelius, T. W., Rauber, M., & Neumann, R. (2009). The experimental investigation of thermal conductivity and the Wiedemann–Franz law for single metallic nanowires. Nanotechnology, 20(32), 325706.
- [23] Mahajan, R., Barkeshli, M., & Hartnoll, S. A. (2013). Non-Fermi liquids and the Wiedemann-Franz law. Physical Review B, 88(12), 125107.
- [24] Stojanovic, N., Maithripala, D. H. S., Berg, J. M., & Holtz, M. (2010). Thermal conductivity in metallic nanostructures at high temperature: Electrons, phonons, and the Wiedemann-Franz law. Physical Review B, 82(7), 075418.
- [25] Ahmad, S., & Mahanti, S. D. (2010). Energy and temperature dependence of relaxation time and Wiedemann-Franz law on PbTe. Physical Review B, 81(16), 165203.
- [26] Garg, A., Rasch, D., Shimshoni, E., & Rosch, A. (2009). Large violation of the Wiedemann-Franz law in Luttinger liquids. Physical review letters, 103(9), 096402.
- [27] López, R., & Sánchez, D. (2013). Nonlinear heat transport in mesoscopic conductors: Rectification, Peltier effect, and Wiedemann-Franz law. Physical Review B, 88(4), 045129.
- [28] Vavilov, M. G., & Stone, A. D. (2005). Failure of the Wiedemann-Franz law in mesoscopic conductors. Physical Review B, 72(20), 205107.
- [29] Wilson, R. B., & Cahill, D. G. (2012). Experimental validation of the interfacial form of the Wiedemann-Franz law. Physical review letters, 108(25), 255901.
- [30] Casian, A. (2010). Violation of the Wiedemann-Franz law in quasi-one-dimensional organic crystals. Physical Review B, 81(15), 155415.
- [31] Zheng, X., Cahill, D. G., Krasnochtchekov, P., Averback, R. S., & Zhao, J. C. (2007). High-throughput thermal conductivity measurements of nickel solid solutions and the applicability of the Wiedemann–Franz law. Acta Materialia, 55(15), 5177-5185.
- [32] Bel, R., Behnia, K., Proust, C., van der Linden, P., Maude, D., & Vedeneev, S. I. (2004). Test of the Wiedemann-Franz law in an optimally doped cuprate. Physical review letters, 92(17), 177003.
- [33] Kim, K. S., & Pépin, C. (2009). Violation of the wiedemann-franz law at the kondo breakdown quantum critical point. Physical review letters, 102(15), 156404.

They include books, research papers, magazines and websites.